# Difference between `yield from $generator` and `return $generator`?

Tags: php, return, generator, yield-from

I have a function that gives back a generator. At the moment it uses `yield from`:

```
function foo()
{
    $generator = getGenerator();
    // some other stuff (no yields!)
    yield from $generator;
}
```

If I replace that `yield from` with a simple `return`, does that change anything in this case? Maybe in the execution? Or performance? Does `yield from` produces a new 'outer' iterator?

I know, in other cases `yield from` can be more flexible because I can use it several times and even mix it with simple `yield`s, however that doesn't matter for my case.

Comment: Do read this [**caution**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield.from) from *docs* that pertains to using `yield from` followed by `iterator_to_array()`

Answer (score 5):

In your case, changing `yield from` to `return` gives the same result. However, if you have `yield` statement before `return`, it won't combine values from `getGenerator()`.

```
function gen_1()
{
    yield 1;
}

function gen_2()
{
    return gen_1();
}

function gen_3()
{
    yield 2;
    return gen_1();
}

function gen_4()
{
    yield 2;
    yield from gen_1();
}

echo "testing gen_2\n";
foreach (gen_2() as $v) {
    echo $v  . "\n";
}

echo "testing gen_3\n";
foreach (gen_3() as $v) {
    echo $v  . "\n";
}

echo "testing gen_4\n";
foreach (gen_4() as $v) {
    echo $v  . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
testing gen_2
1
testing gen_3
2
testing gen_4
2
1
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use `yield from` once at the end of the method like you do above, this does not change things for what is returned by the method. But there is still a difference for the code inside the method: any code before the `yield from` is called when rewinding the iterator at the beginning of the iteration, while the code before the `return` is executed when calling the function, as this function is just a normal function now (actually, this is not specific to `yield from`. It is the behavior of `yield`. See https://3v4l.org/jnPvC for the proof).

The big advantage of `yield from` is that you can use it multiple times in the function, which combined values of all iterators into a single iterator.